# Real method is called instead of SpyOn method in Nest JS unit test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, nestjs

I am implementing unit test in the framework NestJS using Jasmin. And I have a problem with testing one of my service. After long time of debugging I have no idea what's wrong with my code. It looks like my service does't use Spy function and uses real method.

I'm using these versions of packages:

**package.json**

```
"jasmine": "3.1.0"
"@nestjs/testing": "4.6.6"
"@nestjs/common": "4.6.6"
"typescript": "2.6.2"
"node": "8.8.1"
```

I had a problem during testing one method - ***prepareOrderDataOnCreate***.
In this method I invoke 2 methods from other services.

**order.service.ts**

```
@Component()
export class OrdersServiceComponent {
  constructor(
    private userService: UsersServiceComponent,
    private orderStatusService: OrderStatusServiceComponent,
    ...) {}

  async prepareOrderDataOnCreate(user): Promise<Order> {
    const status = await this.orderStatusService.getStatus();
    const user = await this.userService.getOne(user.id);

    return {
      ...
    };
  }
}
```

I mocked both services and created SpyOn for both methods to check if they ***toHaveBeenCalled***. But when I run test get an error:

> Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Function.

After debugging I found out that unit test uses ***usersService.getOne*** not from SpyOn, but from mock file (see below ***user.service.mock.ts***), despite the fact that ***orderStatusService.getStatus*** is used from SpyOn.

**order.service.spec.ts**

```
describe('OrdersServiceComponent', () => {
  let ordersService: OrdersServiceComponent;
  let usersService: UsersServiceMock;

  beforeEach(async() => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [OrdersController],
      components: [
        OrdersServiceComponent,
        {provide: UsersServiceComponent, useClass: UsersServiceMock},
        {provide: OrderStatusServiceComponent, useClass: OrderStatusServiceMock},
        ...
      ]
    }).compile();

    ordersService = module.get<OrdersServiceComponent>(OrdersServiceComponent);
    orderStatusService = module.get<OrderStatusServiceMock>(OrderStatusServiceComponent as any);
    usersService = module.get<UsersServiceMock>(UsersServiceComponent as any);
  });

  it('prepareOrderDataOnCreate method returns order on success', () => {
    spyOn(orderStatusService, 'getStatus').and.stub();
    spyOn(usersService, 'getOne').and.callFake(() => console.log('SPY'));

    ordersService.prepareOrderDataOnCreate({...}).then(res => {
      expect(usersService.getOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(orderStatusService.getStatus).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Instead of Spy unit test uses this mock method:

**user.service.mock.ts**

```
@Component()
export class UsersServiceMock {
  async getOne(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve({});
  }
}
```

It's really strange, because in case when I invoked ***usersService.getOne()*** in this unit test before ***prepareOrderDataOnCreate()*** I got console.log from callFake.

**UPDATE**

I found out that when I run my test and invoke service method ***prepareOrderDataOnCreate***, at first ***userService.getOne*** is Spy function and after any code inside the method ***userService.getOne*** is changed to real function.

```
async prepareOrderDataOnCreate(user): Promise<Order> {
    /*  this.userService.getOne is SPY FUNCTION */

    const status = await this.orderStatusService.getStatus();

    /*  this.userService.getOne is REAL MOCK FUNCTION */

    const user = await this.userService.getOne(user.id);

    ...
  }
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Jasmine expert, but I believe you have to keep references to your spies in variables and run your assertions on those spy objects. Bellow is what it could look like.

```js
it('prepareOrderDataOnCreate method returns order on success', () => {
  const getStatusSpy = spyOn(orderStatusService, 'getStatus').and.stub();
  const getOneSpy = spyOn(usersService, 'getOne').and.callFake(() => console.log('SPY'));

  ordersService.prepareOrderDataOnCreate({...}).then(res => {
    expect(getOneSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(getStatusSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

You can also use `async`/`await`, for a cleaner style.

```js
it('prepareOrderDataOnCreate method returns order on success', async () => {
  const getStatusSpy = spyOn(orderStatusService, 'getStatus').and.stub();
  const getOneSpy = spyOn(usersService, 'getOne').and.callFake(() => console.log('SPY'));

  await ordersService.prepareOrderDataOnCreate({...})

  expect(getOneSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(getStatusSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  
});
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but given the number of upvotes I figured it deserved an answer for other people who might come across it.